# Python object identity

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

I have the following Python code:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, children = []):
        self.name = name
        self.children = children

    def add_child(self, child):
        self.children.append(child)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

def create_tree(num_vertices):
    vs = [Node(str(i)) for i in range(num_vertices)]
    for i in range(num_vertices):
        if 2 * i + 1 < num_vertices:
            vs[i].add_child(vs[2 * i + 1])
        if 2 * i + 2 < num_vertices:
            vs[i].add_child(vs[2 * i + 2])

    return vs[0]

def bfs(top_node, visit):
    """Breadth-first search on a graph, starting at top_node."""
    visited = set()
    queue = [top_node]
    while len(queue):
        curr_node = queue.pop(0)   # Dequeue
        visit(curr_node)           # Visit the node
        visited.add(curr_node)

        # Enqueue non-visited and non-enqueued children
        queue.extend(c for c in curr_node.children
                     if c not in visited and c not in queue)

def visit(tree):
    print tree
```

Now I make the following calls in IDLE:

```
>>> bfs(create_tree(3), visit)
0
1
2
>>> bfs(create_tree(3), visit)
0
1
2
1
2
```

Even though I'm trying to create a new tree each time, I seem to be ending up with the same tree each time (with new nodes being added each time).  Why is that?  In create_tree, I'm creating a new list vs with each function call.

(By the way, this is not homework.  It is Exercise 4.2 in *Think Complexity*, which I'm reading for fun, and the exercise is not to figure out why "[e]ven though I'm trying to create a new tree each time, I seem to be ending up with the same tree each time".  (The problem is to find out why the bfs code is inefficient and I know the answer to that.))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because if you set in init `children = []` it does not create a new list each time, it creates a list the first time and the other times uses the same one; that explains the behavior. in these cases the best thing to do is to write

```
def __init__(self, ..., children = None):
    if children is None: children = []
```

Comment: You could also do `children = children or []`

Comment: Why "if children is None" instead of "if not children" ?

Comment: because with boolean values the best way to behave is to compare them using "is". In this case it's the same thing to write what suggested by Blender or gg.kaspersky, but in many other cases it doesn't make much sense. So, as i dont see any drawback in using this explicit syntax, i think it's better this way :-)